# jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

i have problem about remote jquery autocompete

i get a json object from the server in this format

```
[{"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c800003e","name":"University of Alberta"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c800003f","name":"Athabasca University"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000040","name":"University of Calgary"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000041","name":"University of Lethbridge"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000042","name":"Mount Royal University"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000043","name":"University of Toronto"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000045","name":"Queens University"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000046","name":"University of Waterloo"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000047","name":"McGill University"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000048","name":"University of British Columbia"},
 {"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c8000049","name":"University of Saskatchewan"},
 {"id":"4cec8ead7adf3502a100001f","name":"University of Alberta"}]
```

Now what i need to do is only show the names of the university in the autocomplete list and populate the corresponding id in one hidden field when the user selects the university.

i tried moving aroung formatResult and formatItem with this json object but couldn't figure out how to autocomplete.

It would be helpful if someone explain how to apply formatResult and formatItem methods of jquery autocomplete with json objects

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic data source using c# webmethod See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35620970/5978806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar, but I also have images in my results.  As you can see, my code supports multiple selection.

```
formatItem: function (row, i, n) {
            return '<table><tr><td valign="top"><img src="' + row.ImageUrl + '" /></td><td valign="top">' + row.DisplayName + '</td></tr></table>';
        },
formatResult: function (row, i, n) {
            return row.Id;
        }
}).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
        var results = $("#selectedItems").val();
        $("#selectedItems").val(results + ";" + data.Id)
    });
```

so for yours, I would try this

```
formatItem: function (row, i, n) {
            return '<span>' + row.name+ '</span>';
        },
formatResult: function (row, i, n) {
            return row.id;
        }
}).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
        $("#myHiddenField").val(data.id)
    });
```

EDIT:
Added the result function to put the id into a hidden field

Comment: thanks josh for quick response.
But when i did as you said it didn't work well.
I have my formatItem and formatResult as given below
  formatItem:function(row, i ,n){
   console.log(row);
   return row.name;
  },
  formatResult: function (row, i, n) {
   return row.name;
  }<
I only got only one log from the console.log inside formatItem. The log is similar to this ["[{"id":"4cd8d3b37adf3515c800003e","name":"University of Alberta"},........]"].
if i am not wrong the log is suposed to print all the elements inside the json object.

Comment: i also think the row arg of formatItem is not getting data in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a getJson to get the data i and then use some thing like this to make it autocomplite

```
<body>
    <br /><br />API Reference: <input id="example" /> (try "U")<br /><br />
    ID for selectet university <span id="UniID"></span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('JSonUni.txt' , function(autoData) { // Get the data for autocomplite
                $("#example").autocomplete(autoData, {
                    formatItem: function(item) {
                        return item.name;
                    }
                }).result(function(event, item) {
                    $('#UniID').text(item.id);
                });
            }); // end JSON
        }); // End function
    </script>
</body>
```

Also include this lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
```